# How do I stream data from my iPhone application to an MFi-compliant accessory?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstream, external-accessory, iphone-accessory

I have an MFi-compliant device to which I need to stream realtime data from iPhone. I had a look at the ExternalAccessory framework and the EADSessionController class. I am able to communicate with my MFi device by writing bytes to an output stream.

The problem I am facing is when I try to continuously stream bytes from my iPhone application to the MFi device, bytes are combined into chunks of variable size and sent at same time. Instead, I need to send each packet immediately to the external device.

Is there any way to push the stream to send data immediately, rather than aggregating it in these chunks?